# Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '' (T_ENCAPSED_AND_WHITESPACE) order

Tags: php, parsing, syntax

```
Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '' (T_ENCAPSED_AND_WHITESPACE), expecting identifier (T_STRING) or variable (T_VARIABLE) or number (T_NUM_STRING) in C:\wamp\www\test\base.list.php on line 14
```

Here comes my code

```
if(isset($_GET['sortby']))  
{   
$sortby = "ORDER BY $_GET['sortby']";   
}
```

Error is at "sortby" line.

Comment: This looks like the beginning of a SQL injection vulnerability...

Answer (score 1):

Change your code to:

```
$sortby = "ORDER BY {$_GET['sortby']}"
```

#### Explanation

As specified in the link [Anthony](https://stackoverflow.com/users/49478/anthony) has provided, quoted keys for arrays require "complex" (aka "curly") syntax when embedding expressions in strings.

> ```
> // Works, quoted keys only work using the curly brace syntax
> echo "This works: {$arr['key']}";
> ```

---

And I recommend you to read:

- [How can I prevent SQL injection in PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/60174/1461424)
- [`mysql_real_escape_string`](http://php.net/mysql_real_escape_string)

Comment: Also look at article on curly-braces and string parsing : http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php#language.types.string.parsing.complex